# WiX 3.8 Causing VS 2013 RC Catastrophic Failure

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2013, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have been attempting to install WiX 3.8 for Visual Studio 2013 RC all morning. Every time I attempt to load the "Merge Module Project" or any WiX-related extensions, I am met with a catastrophic error such as this: [image]

`Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000FFFF(E_UNEXPECTED))`

Anyone else receive this error before? If so - how did you fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: That is an awesome error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reinstalled VS 2013 RC, and the error was fixed.